# ¿como imprimir en tkinter? (no en un cuadro sinó en la impresora)

Tags: python, tkinter

Buenoa, llevo intentando un buen rato encontrar algo que me ayude a imprimir una información desde el tkinter del python pero cada vez que busco "Imprimir" sale que para plasmarlo en un cuadro o algo así. Lo que necesito es que agarre una informción de una listbox y la imprima como si se tratara de un documento de Word o algo similar
Les agradezco su ayuda de antemano
PD: mi python es versión 3.8 y está en el sistema operativo Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

segun tengo entendido no se puede imprimir directamente, tendrias que crear una funcion y esta agregarla a un boton de tkinter.

Para agregarla seria algo asi

```
import tempfile
import win32api
import win32print

def __init__(self):
    tk.Button(frame, text='imprimir', command=self.imprimir).grid(
        row=2, columnspan=2, sticky="we")



def imprimit(self):
       archivo = tempfile.mktemp (".txt") 
open (archivo, "w").write ("Esto es una prueba") <- aqui puedes agregar los valores de tu listbox (o puedes crear un documento .docx) 
win32api.ShellExecute ( 
  0,
  "printto",
  filename,
  '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter (),
  ".",
  0
)
```

lo que usas aqui es la libreria de win32 y esta ya manda llamar a windows, recuerda que tomara la impresora por default

Comment: Gracias, en serio me urgía una función para imprimir, si que era fastidioso que pidieras una cosa y te dieran otra. Ahora la pongo en práctica

Comment: Comentame si te ha funcionado, realmente lo que yo hago es mandarlo aun pdf y abrirle la ubicacion donde lo crea y que el mismo usuario lo imprima

Comment: el cófigo funciona, solo debo adaptarlo a mis definiciones pero en general funciona